# Is it possible to disallow jsp execution on tomcat + apache

Tags: java, spring, apache, jsp, tomcat

I have an application tomcat + apache + mod_jk + spring mvc deployed on remote server. After making request to the controller I am having jsp source code in the response. It is not related with spring config cause locally it is working. After debugging mod_jk I see that tomcat returns jsp source.

I think the problem is related with remote tomcat or apache (cause it was configured by our it department). Is it possible to dissalow jsp execution on tomcat or apache (maybe httpd conf)? Plese suggest how can resolve this problem.

Comment: How are you deploying your application?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch we have some tool for deployment, but in general it just puts war file in the tomcat web folder

Comment: Are the JSPs inside Apache's HTDOCS folder rather than under Tomcat's webapps folder?

Comment: @developerwjk No they are in the tomcat webapps  folder. But is it important? How I understand Apache here is like a proxy..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was that jsp compiler was disabled see `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet`, in the `tomcat\conf\web.xml.` It-team says that it is recommend option for production)

Answer (score 1):

Apache Web Server does not execute JSPs, so you're probably getting your JSP from there.

Normally, static files are deployed on Apache Web Server, and dynamic files (JSPs, Custom Tags, classes, etc.) are deployed on Apache Tomcat (where Apache Web server redirects the corresponding requests). Check if your app is deployed this way.

Try to send an HTTP request directly to the Apache Tomcat (without intervention of Apache Web Server, and see what happens)

Comment: i will try but i think it is not possible because tomcat is not visible from outside, only apache